# Clearing client side cache via html headers

Tags: html, http, caching, cookies, keycloak

I have an angular webapp which I serve in a domain/ip at the root address. I use keycloak and gatekeeper for authentication. Sessions are maintained as cookies in the client side. I have a static html page, served in an unique address, whitelisted in my gatekeeper. I redirect my webapp to this page, when the user presses `Logout` in my angular app.

This page on load will clear the sessions in keycloak,and display a `You are logged out!` kind of message. In addition to the static html body it also sets the following response headers

```
"Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
"Pragma": "no-cache"
"Expires": "0"
"Clear-Site-Data": "*"
"Set-Cookie": "kc-access=; Path=/; ..."
"Set-Cookie": "kc-state=; Path=/; ..."
```

All of this works fine. The cookies on the client side get cleared when the user logs out. However, now when the user edits the address bar, and instead of `https://myip/logged_out_page` types `https://myip`, the angular app is loaded from the disk cache.

The session tokens are all invalid and so the network operations fail and so there is no data loss. But this is an extreme usability annoyance.

The cache for the file is not cleared until the browser window is closed and re-opened. Even if I close the browser tab and reopen the same address (the domain/ip) the disk cache is loaded. Only when I close the browser window and re-open the cache is skipped.

[image: disk cache]

One fix that I could think of was, to set the `Cache-Control: "no-cache"` headers in the angular app home page itself, but I do not want that. I want the angular app to use caches as much as possible. I just want all the cache to get cleared when `logged-out` page is loaded (just like how the cookies are cleared).

An image of the response headers that I set and the cookies getting cleared:

Clear headers:

[image: clear cache headers]
[image: clear cookie headers]

Cleared cookies:

[image: cleared cookies]

I understand that `Clear-Site-Data` may not work in non-https sites but why is the `Cache-Control` also not working here ? Is there any way to disable the client side cache when my logout page is loaded. I want all the browser cache for this domain (all subdomains) to be nuked off, when my logout page is loaded, even with non-https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause of the issue. Whatever headers that I set in the angular's `index.html` were irrelevant. The angular app was eventually served via a nginx-ingress, as this was deployed in kubernetes. So, to fix this I had to add a nginx header to explicitly add a `Cache-Control` header and that solved the problem.

The nginx-ingress annotation that I needed is below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "cache-control: no-store";
```

The headers that I set in the `logged-out` page were also irrelevant, because they are applicable only for that page and not the angular app or domain.

Comment: Hey!
Nice solution. Though, this disables cache for all the website right?

Comment: Also, shouldnt the option "no-cache" be better? (instead of no-store)

Comment: To be honest, I do not have the context on this at all. Sorry :(